# The Emperor's New Mind or Shadows of the mind?

Tags: cosmology, mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations

OK - I have never posted on this site before, and I hope this question isn't closed as "request for reference" but here goes:

I'm a software guy who likes to dabble in math, physics and cosmology. Have read "The History of Time" and some books about information theory.

Last night, I started reading Penrose's [The Emperor's New Mind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Mind). In the preface to the current edition, written ten years after the first edition was published, Penrose says that in [Shadows of the Mind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadows_of_the_Mind) he came up with some new ideas as the result of working with [Stuart Hameroff,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuart_Hameroff)  an anesthesiologist by trade. Penrose says these new ideas improve on and surpass the ideas he presents in  Emperor.

**So I'm wondering: Should I just go to Shadows of the Mind and skip Emperor's, or do I need the material he presents in Emperor's, so I can to move on to Shadows?**

Comment: You can read the Shadows without having read the Emperor's Mind first. But if I remember correctly he directs you to  the Emperor for more details about some of the topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not own a copy of "The Emperor's New Mind", nor have I read it.

What I can tell is that "Shadows of the Mind" starts from the beginning, and can be read by it self. I believe that it supersedes "The Emperor's New Mind", even though wikipedia says it is a followup.

[image: Penrose]

Comment: It starts from the beginning, that's what I wanted to know. And since you appear to have an autographed copy, I'll accept your answer. :-)